# using flatten in snowflake: How to target specific nested child in JSON?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, snowflake-schema

I have this issue. I am trying to ONLY get element number 2 (the second 'element') but I am not sure how to target that 'element'. the code below gives all element

```
      select column,
        a.value:element: ready
        from table_name
        ,lateral flatten(input => RAW:root)a
```

context:

```
"root": [
          {
            "element": {
              "ready": "some stuff here",
              "max": "some stuff here"
            },
            "bee": {
              "value": "some stuff here",
              "name": "some stuff here"
            }
          },
          {
            "element": {
              "ready": "some valuable stuff here",
              "Name": "some valuable stuff here"
            },
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? I can write some SQL then

Comment: @FelipeHoffa expecting to have a table with only stuff from element after flattening. the table should come out containing "some valuable stuff here" and "some valuable stuff here" in the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this CTE just for data:

```
WITH table_name as (
    SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"root": [
          {
            "element": {
              "ready": "some stuff here",
              "max": "some stuff here"
            },
            "bee": {
              "value": "some stuff here",
              "name": "some stuff here"
            }
          },
          {
            "element": {
              "ready": "some valuable stuff here",
              "Name": "some valuable stuff here"
            }
             }]}') as RAW
)
```

To get just the "second" element, hard code it!

```
SELECT 
    raw:root[1]:element:ready as ready,
    raw:root[1]:element:Name as name
FROM table_name;
```

| READY | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| "some valuable stuff here" | "some valuable stuff here" |

OR you can filter the FLATTEN results and only accept the index = 2;

```
select
        a.value:element:ready as ready
        ,a.value:element:Name as name
from table_name
    ,lateral flatten(input => RAW:root) a
WHERE a.index = 1
```

| READY | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| "some valuable stuff here" | "some valuable stuff here" |

still quite gross, so maybe you want the "second element" thus some pre-filtered by IS_NULL_VALUE then a QUALIFY

```
WITH table_name as (
    SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"root": [
          {"non-element":123},
          {
            "element": {
              "ready": "some stuff here",
              "max": "some stuff here"
            },
            "bee": {
              "value": "some stuff here",
              "name": "some stuff here"
            }
          },
          {
            "element": {
              "ready": "some valuable stuff here",
              "Name": "some valuable stuff here"
            }
             }]}') as RAW
)
select
        a.value:element:ready as ready
        ,a.value:element:Name as name1
from table_name
    ,lateral flatten(input => RAW:root) a
WHERE is_null_value(a.value:element) = false
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.index ) = 2
```

gives:

| READY | NAME1 |
| --- | --- |
| "some valuable stuff here" | "some valuable stuff here" |

BUT these are all order specific, and JSON is not normally considered order respecting, so it all seems rather dangerous.